# Attiny cores with SPI support?

Tags: attiny, nrf24l01+

It's been done, but the the tutorials I find seems incomplete. What I'm trying to do is make the ATTiny84 talk to the 2.4 GHz NRF24L01+ radio. I understand that in order to do that I need the MCU to talk to the radio by serial. Attiny84 (and 85) does not have serial, hardware any ways.

But as I understand it you can do software serial by USI, but in order to do so the core for the board has to have this modification?

I've searched far and wide. I bump into the cores on Google Code (https://code.google.com/archive/p/arduino-tiny/downloads). I've installed them but SPI is not listed in the list of libraries.
I've got another tinycore (from where I dont know), when I use this one SPI is a library I can reference, but compiling causes

```
error: 'SPIE' was not declared in this scope
```

So, could anyone point me to a known good source of cores to Attiny85 and 84 so I can enable SPI?

Comment: This has been discussed on Github. https://github.com/TMRh20/RF24/issues/236

Comment: The NRF24L01+ does not use "serial" in the usual meaning of asynchronous serial or "software serial" soft UART libraries.  Instead it uses the synchronous serial SPI interface, which the ATtiny series is intended to handle with a hardware/software hybrid approach.  Doing so in bare AVR code is fairly straightforward.